# How to use response.redirect in <asp:button> with ajax, if i want to use class name ajax like in link (<a>)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

My code is here:

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.ajax').live('click', function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#contents').html('<div style="background: #000;"><center><br><img src="http://www.website.com/img/ajax-loader.gif" /><br><br></center></div>');
    $('#contents').load(link + ' .fill-1', function(){
        if($('#contents').html() == ""){
            $('#contents').html('<div style="background: #000; color: #fff;"><center><br>The link could not be found.<br><br></center></div>');
        }
    });
    return(false);
})
})
```

register.aspx

```
<script runat="server">
sub Register(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
'...(what should i write here???)
response.redirect("login.aspx?mode=account")
end sub
</script>
```

and HTML code in register.aspx file (i have my problem here)

```
<div class="fill-1">
<form name="reg" id="reg" runat="server">
  <asp:button text="Register" onclick="Register" runat="server" />
```

and a tag with ajax (old method)

```
  <a href="login.aspx?mode=account" class="ajax">Register</a>
</form>
  <asp:label id="JavaFocus" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why ajax? why not redirect the user to registration page in case they need to register. Then redirect them back to what ever page they were

Comment: I want no page redirecting. It should be like app. Permanent url www.mysite.com/index.aspx or www.mysite.com/